# Python Quickstarts Invalid Syntax on Google Workspace

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-api, google-api-python-client

**Goal:** I'm trying to set up Python in Google Workspace with the goal of creating automation scripts on Google Sheets. Here's the quickstart guide from Google: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python

I did most of the steps except for the "Authorize credentials for a desktop application" section since I'm the one who's going to use this to test the automation extensively first. This means that the installation of the pip package management tool was successful using this code - `pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client google-auth-httplib2 google-auth-oauthlib`

I'm expecting to see a valid output when running `python3 quickstart.py`.

**Tool:** Mu Editor with Python version 3.8.12 (Edited from 3.12.1).

**Problem:** In the final step of the quickstart guide from Google (Run the sample), when I run `python3 quickstart.py`, I get the Invalid Syntax Error. I'm not sure why `quickstart.py` isn't being recognised.

```
Jupyter QtConsole 4.7.7
Python 3.8.12 (default, Oct 18 2021, 00:42:52) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.6.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

python3 quickstart.py
  Cell In [1], line 1
    python3 quickstart.py
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please post the error and the code as text and not as a link.

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

Comment: You try to execute a command for an OS shell (e. g. bash, cmd.exe,...) in a Python shell (which only accepts Python code).

Comment: @MichaelButscher Tried this on the Terminal but there doesn't seem to be a module called google even though I installed this earlier.


`Wis@Wis-Macbook mu_code % python3 quickstart.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Wis/mu_code/quickstart.py", line 3, in <module>
    from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'
Wis@Wis-Macbook mu_code %`

Comment: You may use the wrong Python version or wrong virtual environment. How did you execute the `pip install...`? On the same terminal?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I ran `pip install...` in the interactive shell of Mu Editor. It successfully installed.

Comment: Did you try to run `python3 quickstart.py` in the same shell?